# Make first menu item red on load with scrollspy an jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can someone help me with my code? This code below makes my menu items red on scroll within the div where a "scrollspy" is added. But there is something missing so my first menu item (Home) does not get red when page is loaded, only when I scroll a bit below. I need to have this 1st item red on load. How can I fix this?

**An example code to make first menu item active on load?**

```
window.onload = function() {
      //code?
};
```

**This makes menu item red when added "scrollspy" class on a row in admin**

```
var elems = $('.scrollspy');
$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
  var currentActive = null;
  var currentActiveDistance = -1;
  var currentTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  elems.each(function(index) {
    var elemTop = $(this).offset().top - 102
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var navElem = $('.menu a[href="#' + id + '"]');
    navElem.removeClass('active');
    if (currentTop >= elemTop) {
      var distance = currentTop - elemTop;
      if (currentActiveDistance > distance || currentActiveDistance == -1) {
        currentActive = navElem;
      }
    }
  });

  if (currentActive) {
    currentActive.addClass('active');
  }
});
```

Comment: Did you find my answer useful? @Chocoprins18

Answer (score 1):

Why not use just CSS?

`.nav li a.active {
  background-color: red;
}`

Comment: No, that does not work. The class "active" is added when the view is in the scrollspy

Comment: Can you just add the .active in the HTML? Maybe take a look at [www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_active_element](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_active_element.asp) too

Answer (score 1):

jQuery can be used as below to make first menu item link RED i.e by applying class active.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".menu:first a").addClass('active');
    });
```

Please post your HTML markup if it does not work with your HTML.